# Getting black screen shots while running uft test cases on windows server

Tags: qtp, windows-server-2012-r2, hp-uft

While I am running uft test cases on headed windows server overnight, I have connected to windows server using mstsc.
- we are getting black screen shots, I debugged the reason of black screenshot, and I came to know that when ever user is not interacting to server it puts black screensaver.
- So for the same I change the setting of sleep to never and display off to never but still I am getting black screenshot.

Is there any more setting we need to do on server to not bring black screenshot or any other way for this fix ?

Test Lead

Comment: Do you disconnect from the windows server while running tests?